# Janela Imediate Windows sumiu

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debug, visual-studio-2010

Janela *Imediate Windows* sumiu e não consigo restaurá-la mais. Não aparece a condição no *Menu Edit* do Visual Studio 2010.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Já que esta é uma janela disponível quando se usando o *debug*, que tal dar uma olhada neste menu? Não faria sentido estar no menu Edit. Veja o menu: Debug > Windows > Immediate

Ou pode usar <kbd>CRTL</kbd> <kbd>ALT</kbd> <kbd>I</kbd>. Também deve chegar lá com <kbd>CRTL</kbd> <kbd>D</kbd> <kbd>I</kbd>

[Também é possível procurar na menu Window](https://web.archive.org/web/20160130202338/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wriju/archive/2009/05/14/immediate-window-is-missing-in-visual-studio-menu.aspx), já que ela é uma janela e não uma edição. Ou usar <kbd>CRTL</kbd> <kbd>W</kbd> <kbd>A</kbd> para ir direto ao ponto. Aí ache a janela que quer mostrar. Dá para fazer busca.

Em último caso pode *resetar* o *layout*: Window > Reset Window Layout

Ou Tools > Import and Export Settings... > Reset all settings

Estes casos farão perder todas as configurações atuais mas resolve o problema.

[Documentação](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/immediate-window?view=vs-2015&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397).

[Referência para atalhos](http://www.dofactory.com/reference/visual-studio-shortcuts).